# How do I render an MD file for a custom Storybook addon?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

I am trying to render an MD file passed through parameters.
I can successfully get the text to display, but I really want to get it formatted like an MD file.

I was trying to use `@storybook/addon-docs` but it appears these need to be used in an MDX file instead of directly in React, as I am getting this error: `Uncaught TypeError: storyById is not a function`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParameter } from '@storybook/api';
import { Title, Description } from '@storybook/addon-docs';
import { PARAM_KEY } from '../constants';

const WhatsNewPanel = (props: any) => {
  const value = useParameter(PARAM_KEY, null);
  const item = value ? value : 'No Markdown Defined';
  return (
    <>
      <Title>What&apos;s New?</Title>
      <Description>{item}</Description>
    </>
  );
};

export default WhatsNewPanel;
```

If I remove the `Title` and `Description` components, I can see the unformatted MD text successfully.

Does anyone know of an API or way to render the MD file formatted?

My [PR code](https://github.com/kennethbigler/whats-new/pull/4/files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[react-markdown](https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown) was my first attempt which worked sufficiently, but then I found that if I pulled `import { Description } from "@storybook/components";` instead of `@storybook/addon-docs`, everything worked as expected.

Code can be seen in my [Pull Request](https://github.com/kennethbigler/whats-new/pull/4/files).

Comment: Please note that rendering markdown in V7 using Description is deprecated.